# org-babel for Jython?

Tags: org-babel

Is there an org-babel for the [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) (not Python, it must be Jython) programming language? I am especially interested in session based evaluation for Jython. I am considering writing my own ob-jython.el, but want to make sure this has not been tackled yet.

Comment: What features would you miss using `ob-python` with the `jython` interpreter instead of `python`?

Comment: @T.Verron How does one go about swapping out the Python interpreter?

Comment: @Drew, the tag should really say "jython" not "jpython". Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the babel python interpreter to jython with:

`(setq org-babel-python-command "jython")`

Comment: This seems to work, at least partially. A Python (which is really Jython) Buffer/shell is created --similar to what happens with Python-- but it seems org has trouble communicating to the Jython process. The results are somewhat garbled though they do return in a somewhat readable state. Also I don't believe session based evaluations are working. I will continue to experiment, and let you know what I find.

Comment: Actually, I retract what I said earlier. Session mode does seem to work as long as you remember to stay in session mode with the :session source block argument. Moreover, the output seems to only be garbled with the first evaluation. Subsequent code blocks seem to look good. Great. Thanks @Jesse.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)